# Unable to find file created by Poppler-Utils on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, poppler

I'm running an app on Heroku that requires processing before uploading to external storage. My working dir is /usr/src/app/ and the program can no longer find files. Here's what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install poppler-utils && apt-get clean
FROM python:alpine3.7
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY upload.py /usr/src/app/
COPY index.html /usr/src/app/
COPY success.html /usr/src/app/
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD python ./upload.py
```

This is how I call poppler

```
commandCall = 'pdftohtml -c -s "' + newPath + '" "' + htmlPath + '"'
subprocess.call(commandCall, shell=True)
```

It should save in the working directory, but when I go to use a file created by it, it isn't able find it. I'm using Tornado as my HTTP handler and I'm wondering if the issue is with using a sub process call in a container.

Comment: `CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi` runs the command in the foreground though. Maybe its not getting to the code that actually creates the file you need

Answer (score 0):

The current `Dockerfile` as-is isn't buildable.

First, the command to start `gunicorn` expects a `wsgi` module that is never copied before getting passed as an argument to `gunicorn` executable.

Also, multiple commands are listed in the Dockerfile. [Docker only respects the last command as the entrypoint command to run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

Your dockerfile can be cleaned up as follows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install poppler-utils && apt-get clean

FROM python:alpine3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

RUN adduser -D myuser
USER myuser

CMD gunicorn --user myuser --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi:app
```

The above file assumes that there is a `wsgi.py` module in the folder where `docker build` command will be executed and in that file is declared an `app` name which binds to an object that implements WSGI application interface.

Test that you can build it locally by running `docker build -t poppler .`.

Also note that even for docker images, [the filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime). 
So the [file is only persisted for the lifetime of your dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku).

If you necessarily require to run multiple processes in the entrypoint command, consider using [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) for that.